# How to find and display a group of objects with a specific tag using acts as taggable (redux)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I want to display a list of articles in my tag's show view. I'm using the acts as taggable redux plugin in a Rails 2.3.2 and SQLite3 app. I've got as far as the [basic example](http://github.com/geemus/acts_as_taggable_redux/blob/8d032f5ac86a36d31478b384226b715192614d5e/README) takes me, assigning tags and then displaying a list of them with the article.

Now I want to display a list of articles belonging to a tag but get the following error:

```
undefined method `article' for #<Tag id: 1, name: "various", taggings_count: 1>
```

### Models

/article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base  
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

/user.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base  
  acts_as_tagger
end
```

### Controller

/tags_contoller.rb

```
def show
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  @articles = @tag.articles
end
```

### View

/tags/show.html.erb

```
<% for article in @articles %>  
   ...  
<% end %>
```

Here is a [link to the migration file](http://pastie.org/517915).

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Geemus, author of acts as taggable redux for explaining this to me.

To display a list of articles with a specific tag I just needed to change the tags_controller from:

/tags_contoller.rb

```
def show
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  @articles = @tag.articles
end
```

to:

Controller
/tags_contoller.rb

```
def show
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  @articles = @tag.tagged
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the plugin is not the one to blame here, it's sqlite that's bringing you trouble. I encountered this one before - it seems sqlite can't understand 'table_name.column_name' syntax, even though it's not mentioned on the website. In my case I just switched to MySQL, and the whole thing went without a problem. See if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've run into trouble getting the MySQL Gem working in Rails 2.3.2. Will let you know if it fixes the above issue.

Comment: Finally got MySQL working with rails 2.3.2. Unfortunately it did not fix the issue which had more to do with my lack of understanding of the plugin :).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a model named Object. Give it a name that has no overlap with Ruby system classes, such as ApplicationObject or MediaObject.

I could speculate on why that's causing the issues it is, but it would only be speculation. Open classes is a wonderful feature of Ruby, but it means you need to be careful naming your classes so they're distinct from Ruby's and Rail's classes.

Comment: And rename all your references to object, @objects, etc., too.

Comment: my apologies, by naming the model object I was giving a general name to the "thing" the being tagged. I've changed "object" to "article" to make this clearer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it, if you actually had a model named Object it would have failed much earlier and more mysteriously. :)